# String formatting when updating dictionary with specifiers and dictionary comprehensions

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, formatting, dictionary-comprehension

I want to ask a question about updating a python dictionary using string formatting.

I'm following a tutorial on [matplotlib](https://realpython.com/python-matplotlib-guide/#a-burst-of-color-imshow-and-matshow) from real python and there is some code that confuses me.

```
sides = ('left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom')
nolabels = {s: False for s in sides}
nolabels.update({'label%s' % s: False for s in sides})
print(nolabels)
```

The first two lines make sense - that's just listing the keys for `sides` and the initial dictionary for `nolabels`.

However, the following line I've tried to understand as so:

```
nolabels.update({'label%s' % s: False for s in sides})
```

We're updating the `nolabels` dictionary using a dictionary comprehension, and we've adding new keys, which are made from the old keys but preceded with the word `label` e.g. `labelleft`, `labelright` etc.

What I am struggling to understand is how the formatting takes place.
My guess is that each iteration of the dictionary comprehension is run e.g.

1. Obtain the first item in `sides` `->` `left`
2. make a new key and value pair in the dictionary, but make the key `label`+`left` = `labelleft`
3. store the key, value pair and repeat for all items in the `sides` dictionary.

Am I on the right lines with regards to the program flow, or have I messed it up entirely?

Comment: Putting aside that it *pseudo*-is `label+left = labelleft` instead of `label+left = label left`, yep, you are on the right lines.

Comment: @keepAlive I'm glad! I've updated the post to reflect what you've said. Out of interest, the `%s` codes - do you know specifically what they're called? I've tried to look for an answer but I get thrown towards C-style strings! I know Python is based loosely on C but I was wondering whether there is a discussion that purely discusses the codes in a Pythonic context?

Comment: for formatting codes see https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Comment: for me the example seems a bit convoluted, I'd use `sides = ['left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom']` and `dict.fromkeys(sides + [f'label{s}' for s in sides], False)`

Comment: You are welcome. It is called [(old style) string formatting](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/).